# Spring - Cast Object to List

Tags: spring

I have an object that I want to retrieve, not just the object but the associated children.

Controller in which if I do something like this:

```
         List<UserEntity>  u = (List<UserEntity>) userService.getUserByID(userId);
         List<UserEntityDTO> userDTO = (List<UserEntityDTO>) new UserEntityDTO();

         for (UserEntity user: u) {


           UserEntityDTO dto = new UserEntityDTO();

           dto.setUserId(user.getUserId());
           dto.setsModule(moduleService.getSetterModules(user.getUserId()));
           dto.setcModule(moduleService.getCheckerModules(user.getUserId()));

           userDTO.add(dto);

        }

        map.addAttribute("setter", userDTO);
```

There is an error

```
  java.lang.ClassCastException: com.myproject.app.model.UserEntity cannot be cast to java.util.List
com.myproject.app.controller.UserController.getSetPage(UserController.java:320)
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:219)
org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:132)
org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:104)
org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandleMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:746)
org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:687)
org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:80)
org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:925)
org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:856)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:915)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:811)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:796)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:118)
org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:84)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:113)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:103)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:113)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:54)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:45)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(BasicAuthenticationFilter.java:150)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
org.springframework.security.web.authentication.ui.DefaultLoginPageGeneratingFilter.doFilter(DefaultLoginPageGeneratingFilter.java:91)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:183)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:105)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:87)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:192)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:160)
org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:346)
org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:259)
```

I would like some insight into the right way of getting the object and the associated persistent set. Or is there is another more straightforward way then I would appreciate the pointers.

Comment: Oh boy, yet another long and useless stack trace… (I see so many of those when working with my code, and almost always the frames at the bottom from the frameworks are totally useless. Except for the rare occasions when something goes very badly wrong with the frameworks themselves.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that error is thrown on this line:

```
List<UserEntity>  u = (List<UserEntity>) userService.getUserByID(userId);
```

`userService.getUserByID(userId)` probably returns single instance of `UserEntity`. So if you want to have a List you have to wrap it like this:

```
List<UserEntity>  u = new ArrayList<UserEntity>();
u.add(userService.getUserByID(userId));
```

Same problem is also on second line, you are trying to cast instance of `UserEntityDTO` to `List` as noted by Alex. You have to wrap it in the same way:

```
List<UserEntityDTO> userDTO = new ArrayList<UserEntityDTO>();
userDTO.add(new UserEntityDTO());
```

But I doubt you really wanted to add new empty instance of `UserEntityDTO` to the list so you can skip the second line.
I also doubt you really need to wrap those entities and DTO objects in Lists.

Comment: I have done it. Thank you so much. This has been a problem for days. I did need to wrap the DTO objects into the list just to get the associated objects. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

This is NOT correct: `(List) new UserEntityDTO()`.
It should be

```
List<UserEntityDTO> list = new ArrayList<UserEntityDTO>();
list.add(new UserEntityDTO());
```

Comment: Thank you for providing me with the pointer on the list. I appreciate it.